# Monitor Websphere Liberty Profile with JConsole

Tags: java, jconsole, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to monitor my WLP v8.5.5 with JConsole.

My Liberty profile is up and running and has SSL properlly configured.
I also have configured as features the monitor-1.0 and restConnector-1.0.

After that I sftp'ed from my WLP the restConnector.jar to my machine and created a keystore on my machine as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore)

After that I'm trying to start JConsole with this command:

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\lib\jconsole.jar;
                              C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\lib\tools.jar;
                              <whereIDownloaded>\restConnector.jar" 
         -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="<locationToCreated>\keystore.jks" 
         -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<password> 
         -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks 
         -J-Dcom.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.disableURLHostnameVerification=true
```

However, when I try to connect to my WLP via remote with the string:

```
service:jmx:rest://<ip>:<httpsPort>/IBMJMXConnectorREST
```

As a credential I'm passing a user configured on `<administrator-role>`.

I get a JConsole error saying:

```
Secure connection failed. Retry insecurely?
```

I don't get why I'm seeing this error, and I don't see any logs to see why it failed.
My next step if getting the keystore from WLP and try that on my machine but I don't think that makes much sense.

Does anyone have any suggestion on where should I look for logs or on that I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Reference:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_mon.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-6&lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you don't have `localConnector-1.0` feature. If you have that, please remove it. You can find more details here [Remote monitoring of Liberty with Health Center](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/29458/remote-monitoring-of-liberty-with-health-center.html). Although it discusses Health Center connection, I was testing using JConsole also.

**UPDATE**
You might be invoking console with incorrect params - it should be `trustStore` not `keystore` see below. And for start use `key.jks` copied from Liberty (as you need Liberty certificate as trusted)

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%/lib/jconsole.jar;
                         %JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar;
                         %WLP_HOME%/clients/restConnector.jar
     -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=key.jks 
     -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=Liberty 
     -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks
```

For details check [Configuring secure JMX connection to the Liberty](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_restconnector.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-3-3-10-1&lang=en)

Comment: I don't have that feature enabled. I'll check that health center out. It looks good.

Comment: @Silva Updated answer. Try to take `key.jks` from Liberty and switch to truststore.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you know if this works with PKCS12 stores? It's what I have. JConsole tells me that it can't connect, but Health Center from IBM tells me that "SSL Keystore password incorrect". However, I have this same store working on my liberty profile and I know I'm inputing the right password. So it must be store types right?

Comment: Your answer was right, I just needed to tune it to my problem. I had a pfx store so I had to export the certificate from out of there and import it into my locally created store. With this done, I was able to run JConsole smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional note - you must not have a `webAppSecurity` entry with `loginFormURL` set in your server.xml as this will cause the JMX login to fail (e.g., `<webAppSecurity loginFormURL="login.html"/>` is problematic). Each individual WAR needs to set their own `login-config` and not rely on any global method of configuring logins.

`